# Ruby on Rails / HAML image_path not working in else condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm currently working on a project on RoR with haml, and i have an issue i have never saw before.

I have an "user profile" with an optional image. I want to show the image if it exists, if not, i show a placeholder (stored in assets  => "admin/avatar.png". So, here is my sample code below:

```
-unless @user.image.nil?
    =image_tag @user.image.url,class:"img-responsive img-circle",style:"width:150px;height:150px;margin:auto;"
-else
    %img.img-responsive.img-circle{:src => image_path("admin/avatar.png"),style:"width:150px;height:150px;margin:auto;"}
%img.img-responsive.img-circle{:src => image_path("admin/avatar.png"),style:"width:150px;height:150px;margin:auto;"}
```

The first

```
%img.img-responsive.img-circle{:src => image_path("admin/avatar.png"),style:"width:150px;height:150px;margin:auto;"}
```

is not working (and shows "missing") and the seconde is actually working. I'm a bit lost with this.

Anyone ?

thanks.

Comment: are you sure that 'missing' is not from `image_tag`?

Comment: what does `@user.image.url` equal to?

Comment: @Maxime Bauer, can you post your user model code as well, because if there is default url defined in your user model then it will always execute the first block instead of else block

Comment: Nah, @user.image.url is equal to "
/system/users/images/000/000/003/original/lel.jpg?1474748997 " for example, its the paperclip attribute. And btw my use rmodel is almost empty and i don't define any default url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unless else` is a kind of code smell

A solution I'd propose:

```
- if @user.image.present?
 = image_tag(@user.image.url, class:"img-responsive img-circle",style:"width:150px;height:150px;margin:auto;")
- else
 = image_tag('admin/avatar', class:"img-responsive img-circle", style:"width:150px;height:150px;margin:auto;")
```

Comment: Well it worekd. Btw i don't know why the unless else condition generate errors when i want to link an asset image. Thats weird, Thanks :)